# Why is my if returning the "else-part", even if the condition is false?

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement

I am very new at this, maybe I don't know exactly how to ask this, but hope someone can help me.

I am using a short if statement inside a get function for a project but it is not returning what I expected. Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const stockModel = require("../models.js").Stock;

async function getPrice(stock) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://stock-price-checker-proxy.freecodecamp.rocks/v1/stock/${stock}/quote`, {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  });
  const { symbol, latestPrice } = await response.json();
  return { symbol, latestPrice };
}

module.exports = function (app) { 
  
  app.route('/api/stock-prices') 
     .get(async function (req, res) {
    // get all parameters necessary for response
    const { stock, like } = req.query;
    const { symbol, latestPrice } = await getPrice(stock);

    // if cant find stock
    if(!symbol) {
      ////// console.log(like);
      res.json({ stockData: {
        error: "invalid symbol",
        likes: like ? 1 : 0
      }});
      ////// console.log(like);
      return;
    }
  });
};
```

Like comes from this checkbox input, and when I console.log like, it returns true when the box is checked, and false when it is not. Independently of that, the if statement still returns 1

```
<form id="testForm2" class="border">
    <input type="text" name="stock" placeholder="GOOG" required="" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="like" value="true" /> Like?
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Get Price!</button>
</form>
```

The short if-statement is always returning 1, whether "like" is true or false (checkbox is checked or not).

When the box is unchecked both console.logs display false, but the res.json still displays likes: 1

I have changed uncountable things and not yet found the reason for this, I don't know if it might be somewhere else, but the rest of the code is a boilerplate, not made by me, so it is supposedly correct. I commented out everything else on my api.js file, so it wont influence it.

I also have a db connection as follows:

model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const stockSchema = new Schema({
    symbol: { type: String, required: true },
    likes: { type: [String], default: [] }
});

const Stock = mongoose.model('Stock', stockSchema);
exports.Stock = Stock;
```

connection:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const db = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: "*whether "like" is true or false*" it will be `"true"` or `"false"` as a string, not a boolean. And non-empty strings are truthy.

Answer (score 0):

If `console.log` shows that you are returning `"false"` (notice the quotations) then the value for `like` is coming back as a String type, not as a Boolean. If that is the case, both "true" and "false" will resolve as truthy because they are non-empty strings. If this is the case, we can simply alter the logic in the ternary slightly to explicitly check for a "true" string value.

```js
if(!symbol) {
  res.json({ stockData: {
    error: "invalid symbol",
    likes: like === "true" ? 1 : 0
  }});
  return;
}
```

You may instead want to alter how that value is being saved at an earlier point so that it resolves as a Boolean, especially if you are going to use the value later as this can obviously cause trouble if you logically are expecting a Boolean but instead are given a string wrapped representation of one. But if this is a one-off value check, and if you know that the value can only either be "true" or "false" and nothing else, since it doesn't seem like you are going to use the value again the above solution would probably be sufficient.

You could also add even more logic to it so that it accepts both Booleans and Strings and then coerce it into a number using the unary plus operator (`+`) to avoid the ternary. Something like:

```js
if(!symbol) {
  res.json({ stockData: {
    error: "invalid symbol",
    likes: +(like === true || like === "true")
  }});
  return;
}
```

The + at the beginning of the conditional is the unary plus operator and when the conditions inside the parentheses resolve to either true or false it will coerce that boolean into either a 1 (for true) or a 0 (for false). This may be a little less clear to people though as to what is getting returned, and it may be more than you need if `like` can only ever be "true" or "false", but it should work well.

Comment: ok thank you for the detailed explanation... like I said it was my first time asking a question here and by trying to make it clearer I forgot quotes actually MEAN something when coding... but it was just a mistake to what I wrote. the console.logs don't display quotes, they display a boolean false. I had also already thought of that option, but trying to make the condition meet both boolean or string true, doesn't work either

Comment: Well then we need more information and more code about what `req.query` is returning for `like` and why it is always returning `false`. You have not provided us enough information for anyone to figure that out. Provide more information and I will edit my answer.

Comment: thank you. I tried adding more info to the original post, but I don't know what else I info could be influencing and is worth sharing. I will restart this project and go step by step from the beginning, se if I find anything

Comment: In the `likes` ternary statement that currently returns either `1` or `0`, i would next try replacing the `1` with `console.log('like - true condition: ', like)` and the `0` with `console.log('like - false condition: ', like)` to see what the value actually is when the condition is being tested inside the ternary.